# Consumir API REST XML PHP

Tags: php, api

actualmente estoy tratando de consumir un servicio API de Banxico con el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
// Función para llamar al webservice y devolver el resultado en un array

$data=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest/service/v1/series/SF43718/datos/oportuno?token=e33131d7da9d1fb90fb13b93633b2fb55a55d032c2596d364d684aca358e4'),true);
print_r($data);

?>
```

Esto me arroja el siguiente array

> Array ( [bmx] => Array ( [series] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [idSerie] => SF43718 [titulo] => Tipo de cambio Pesos por dólar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de determinación (FIX) [datos] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fecha] => 10/12/2021 [dato] => 20.8922 ) ) ) ) ) )

Mi pregunta o duda es como puedo imprimir los valores de fecha y dato.
e intentado asi:

```
foreach ($data['serie']['obs'] AS $d){
echo $d['dato'];
}
```

Pero me dice que no esta definido dato.
Donde puedo encontrar un ejemplo para orientarme?

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías probar con algo así para poder solicitar datos a la api: `print_r($data['bmx']['series'][0]['fecha']);` y para dato `print_r($data['bmx']['series'][0]['dato']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si analizas la estructura del objeto:

```
Array ( [bmx] => 
  Array ( [series] => 
    Array ( [0] => 
      Array ( [idSerie] => SF43718 
              [titulo] => Tipo de cambio Pesos por dólar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de determinación (FIX) 
              [datos] => Array (
                           [0] => Array ( 
                                    [fecha] => 10/12/2021 
                                    [dato] => 20.8922 
                                  ) 
                                ) 
            ) 
         ) 
      ) 
)
```

Podrás ver con claridad que `fecha` y `dato` se encuentran en la ruta:

```
bmx -> series -> 0 -> datos -> 0
```

Por tanto, puedes acceder así:

```
#Aquí $datos apuntará al nodo donde está lo que te interesa
#Lo creamos una sola vez, para no repetir constantemente $data["bmx"]["series"][0]["datos"][0]
$datos=$data["bmx"]["series"][0]["datos"][0];
$fecha=$datos["fecha"];
$dato=$datos["dato"];
```

La clave no es otra que seguir la ruta de cada elemento y en eso te ayuda mucho mostrar tus arrays indentados.

Supongamos que quieres acceder también a `titulo`:

```
echo $data['bmx']['series'][0]['titulo'];
```

La estructura del array te dice ya cómo acceder a cada elemento, tanto si lo quieres hacer directamente o si quieres iterar sobre los arrays anidados en algún caso. Con esa técnica, ningún array, por complejo que sea, se te resistirá.

Si fuese un objeto, sería lo mismo, sólo que en lugar de la sintaxis de array: `$elArray[elIndiceNumerico]` o `$elArray['elIndiceAlfanumerico']` se usaría la sintaxis: `$elObjeto->laPropiedad`.

Si `$data` fuese un objeto, lo escribiríamos así:

```
echo $data->bmx->series->0->titulo;
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ya entendi como hacerlo siguiendo la ruta del array para poder sacar el valor que requiero, mil gracias.