# ¿Como obtener estos valores de un stdClass desde php?

Tags: php, json

Estoy aprendiendo a decodificar y codificar json a traves de php y tengo el siguiente ejercicio

```
{
    "bmx": {
        "series": [
            {
                "idSerie": "22gh",
                "titulo": "Cambio",
                "datos": [
                    {
                        "fecha": "1/1/2020",
                        "dato": "20.23930"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Requiero obtener el valor de "fecha" y "dato", he intentado con foreach pero sin exito alguno.
Considero que me estoy equivocando con el orden de los objetos
¿Cuál sería el orden correcto de los objetos para almacenar esos 2 datos en una variable?

Intenté esto pero no me funcionó

```
$data_Rate = _getCurrentRate_(); //Save result as a variable 
$response_Rate = json_decode($data_Rate, true); 
$bmx = $data_Rate['bmx']; 
$series = $bmx['series']; 
$datos = $series['datos']; $currentDate = $datos['0']; 
$currentPrice = $datos['1'];
```

Comment: ´´´$data_Rate = _getCurrentRate_();  //Save result as a variable
    $response_Rate = json_decode($data_Rate, true);
        $bmx = $data_Rate['bmx'];
        $series = $bmx['series'];
        $datos = $series['datos'];
        $currentDate = $datos['0'];
        $currentPrice = $datos['1'];´´´ Intente esto pero no me funcionó

Comment: Me parece que estás mareando mucho los datos. ¿`$data_Rate` qué es exactamente? Si es un objeto, puedes acceder directamente a las propiedades desde él sin necesidad de más conversiones, por tanto, `json_decode` está de más aquí. Para acceder a las propiedades se hace del mismo modo explicado [en otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/502930/29967), sólo que si trabajas con objetos, la sintaxis es así: `$elObjeto->laPropiedad`, mientras que en los arrays, la sintaxis es así: `$elArray[elIndiceNumerico]` o `$elArray['elIndiceAlfanumerico']`. No hay más misterio...

Answer (score 2):

Posiblemente tu problema se deba a la forma cómo está interpretando PHP el archivo JSON. Verifica la documentación de [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php).

Vamos a usar este JSON de ejemplo:

```
$json = '{
    "bmx": {
        "series": [
            {
                "idSerie": "22gh",
                "titulo": "Cambio",
                "datos": [
                    {
                        "fecha": "1/1/2020",
                        "dato": "20.23930"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}';
```

Si json_decode solo tiene un parámetro, PHP interpreta el JSON como un objeto `object(stdClass)`

```
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data);
echo $data->bmx->series[0]->datos[0]->fecha;
```

La salida será:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [bmx] => stdClass Object
...
)
1/1/2020
```

Como eso no es un array, si no un objeto especial, al hacer:

```
echo $data['bmx']['series'][0]['datos'][0]['fecha'];
```

obtendremos: *Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array*

---

Ahora, colocando el parámetro true al json_decode:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($data);
echo $data['bmx']['series'][0]['datos'][0]['fecha'];
```

La salida será:

```
Array (
    [bmx] => Array
...
)
1/1/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que veo mal es la asignación de la variable $bmx. Lo correcto sería lo siguiente:

```
$bmx = $response_Rate['bmx'];
```

Si haces un print_r de la variable $response_Rate verás esto:

```
Array
(
    [bmx] => Array
        (
            [series] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [idSerie] => 22gh
                            [titulo] => Cambio
                            [datos] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [fecha] => 1/1/2020
                                            [dato] => 20.23930
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Por lo tanto para acceder por ejemplo a la fecha:

```
$currentPrice = $bmx['series][0]['datos'][0]['fecha'];
```